# Cancel an ASP.NET callback processing

Tags: asp.net, callback

I am loading a gridview  using  a code based on this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366515%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

I am using callbacks to populate the grid, sometimes there is a lot of data or the user wants to cancel.

How can I cancel the callback from being processed on the server when user hit cancel??

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot cancel the server side call back processing once initiated. At the most, you can have some client (browser) side logic that will ignore callback results.

Regardless, I will suggest you to use ASP.NET AJAX (`UpdatePanel` or `Script Services`) rather than using `ICallbackEventHandler`. It's quite simple to use and more flexible. Besides, you also have options such as cancelling callbacks : see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163413.aspx#S2) for cancelling update panel callback (note that cancel really means stop waiting for (& ignoring) callback results, the server side processing would happen).

Answer (score 3):

Searched quite extensively and found that it is possible to `Cancel Server Tasks with ASP.NET & AJAX`

Although I'm not good with AJAX, Found some links that will help you,

Here's how to [Canceling Server Tasks with ASP.NET & AJAX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163380.aspx) and here's a [forum thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1550060.aspx) on something similar to your problem.

Hope it helped !

Answer (score 1):

Once you've initiated a request to the server, the client cannot cancel it. Ignoring the mechanics around any possible "cancellable method", you've started a request with the server. Any further communication will result in a new request, so that original request will continue until it has finished. Remember HTTP is a stateless protocol, each request has no knowledge of any previous request, and because of that, how could it cancel a previous request?

You're best bet would be to just ignore the server response, **or** if you actually need to cancel a long running task that may still be processing on the server, you need to bake in that support yourself, as the web server will not natively support it. To do that, you'll likely need some way of persisting the task state across multiple http requests, and have the original request (the one running that task) be monitoring some sort of cancellation flag.

Just remember though, in the above scenario, you wouldn't be cancelling the request, but the task the request is running.